# Maximum call stack size exceeded in socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

There are two pages, mario.html and index.html. index.html has inside of it an iframe of mario.html.

index.html code:

```
const socket = io();

setInterval(() => {
    socket.emit('host update things',game.solids,game.characters,game.scenery)
}, 1000);
```

mario.html code:

```
const socket = io();

socket.on('server uptade things',(serverSolids,serverCharacters,serverScenery)=>{
    console.log(serverCharacters3)
    solids=serverSolids
    characters=serverCharacters
    scenery=serverScenery
})
```

server.js:

```
  socket.on('host update things',(solids,characters,scenery)=>{
    room=rooms.find((item)=>{
      return item.host==socket.id
    })
    socket.broadcast.to(room.id).emit('server uptade things',solids,characters,scenery)
  })
```

I miss the code to enter and quit rooms, because it is working.
When I run the server and open the index.html page, the console show:

> is-binary.js:28 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

(there isn't an is-binary.js file in my  project)

Comment: `uptade` looks like a typo for `update`

Comment: yes, it is but this don't resolve the bug